# How to perform stress test against sharepoint site using threads

Tags: testing, sharepoint-2010, stress-testing, performance-testing, sharepointfoundation2010

I want to analyze the performance (hence its weak points) of a sharepoint site doing stress test activity. What is needed to be done is call some methods exposed via web service that do the following things inside the sharepoint site:

```
-create a new group 
-add a content to the group 
-add an attachment to the content 
-delete the content 
-delete the previously created group
```

What is required is a simulation of a situation where there are 4500 users trying to do these operations concurrently (at the same time or more realistically within a short timespan, for example within 5 seconds).

We want to register the execution time of each operation (web method, for example of the "create new group"), too. I thought I could simulate these operations via a console applications using threads and stopwatchs. Is there anyone who has encountered a similar problem and can give me any existing solutions or hints to do it "the right way"? For 
example how can I obtain that all threads start at the same instant? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am a user of Visual Studio Load Testing since 2 years, and I find it very powerfull and easy to use. You can run integration tests, navigation in a web site, simulate database load, ...  in fact, everything. Because it is a MS application, it is also fully compatible with all MS products like Sharepoint : it's easier to call a WCF service from a unit test than another technology (how to test nettcpbinding ?). You can also use the Visual Studio Profiler for instrumenting your code (and see what line of code is expensive or event ADO.net interactions). You can also easily extend the load testing by many extensibility points.

One important thing is that VS laod testing is "intrusive". It will note only collect response time, request lengths, ... but also all performance counters, database queries, ... All this metrics are saved in a dedicated database like SQLExpress for reporting. There is an AddOn for Excel.

**Juste one important note (available for all load testing solutions !)** :

You can run load tests from a developer machine or even a single dedicated machine, but you usually can't generate enough traffic to really see how the application responds (you machine can not simulate 500 concurrent users because of limited CPU/Memory/Network) . In order to simulate a lot of users, you'll set up what is known as a Load Test Rig.
  [image: test rig]

A test rig is made up of a Test Controller machine and one or more Test Agent machines as shown in Figure 1. The controller manages and coordinates the agent machines and the agents generate load against the application. The test controller is also responsible for collecting performance monitor data from the servers under test and optionally from the test rig machines.

Here are some links :

- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293540.aspx)
- [Dave's introduction](http://davefancher.com/2010/10/01/web-performance-load-testing-in-visual-studio-2010/)

Answer (score 0):

Not saying Visual Studio Load Testing is not a great tool. There are tools, like Tsung, Eventlet (and many others) that can support well over thousands of concurrent users.

Good luck.